# RSS Feed が遅延している

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求

RSSフィードについてフィードバックしたいと思います。「最近の質問」 (`http://ja.stackoverflow.com/feeds`)がRSSリーダーごとに内容が異なります。2017/4/7 12:13 JST時点で次のように違いが見られます。

1. Thunderbird : `2017/4/6 8:13` が最新の質問となっており遅延している
2. Firefox : サイト上の新着と同じ

feeds の内容を確認すると `<updated>2017-04-05T23:56:07Z</updated>` と表示されました。こうやって確認しました。

```
$ curl -s http://ja.stackoverflow.com/feeds | gzip -dc | head -10
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:re="http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0">
    <title type="text">最近の質問 - スタック・オーバーフロー</title>
    <link rel="self" href="http://ja.stackoverflow.com/feeds" type="application/atom+xml" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions" type="text/html" />
    <subtitle>次の URL からの最新の 30 件: ja.stackoverflow.com</subtitle>
    <updated>2017-04-05T23:56:07Z</updated>
    <id>http://ja.stackoverflow.com/feeds</id>
    <creativeCommons:license>http://www.creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/rdf</creativeCommons:license>
```

なお、複数の環境で同じ結果なのでキャッシングなどの影響ではないと思います。私のPCと、AWS上のLinuxインスタンス どちらも同じ結果になりました。

Answer (score 3):

遅れてますね。

- アクセス元の地域
- ログイン状況 (Cookieがあるか)

が影響していそうです。
[以前報告した問題](//ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2251)でも地域による差がありました。
ざっと試した限りでは、以下のようになっています。

- ログインしてアクセスすると地域によらず、最新のフィードが得られる
- 匿名でのアクセスでは、古いフィードが得られ、どれくらい古いかは、どこからアクセスするかによる
- 匿名アクセスでの遅延は相当あり、特に本家のフィード (https://stackoverflow.com/feeds) は10日近く遅れているように見える

フィードリーダーはログインセッションなど持たずにアクセスするものですから、改善するといいですね。

---

例として、ほぼ同時刻の https://ja.stackoverflow.com/feeds へのアクセスで以下のような違いが見られました (最初の`<updated>`タグを抜きだしています)。

`<updated>2017-04-07T08:15:37Z</updated>`  # use session cookie (from Japan)
`<updated>2017-04-07T04:26:06Z</updated>`  # from Japan
`<updated>2017-04-04T20:50:23Z</updated>`  # from USA
`<updated>2017-04-04T10:29:52Z</updated>`  # from Russia